# Image Naming Convention for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

what is the Image **Naming Convention** for **iPhone 5** like @2x for retina screens.

Comment: Make sure that the @2x images are double the size of the original image.. eg : if a.png is of size 100 x 100 pixels then a@2x.png should be 200 x 200 pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the same. The @2x just means it's a retina image.

The only difference is the 568@2x (or whatever it is) for the splash screen but Xcode renames that file for you anyway.

Just keep using @2x.png

Comment: i dont think so. you have to provide 3 different resolutions for normal, retina and iphone5 screens especially for background images that occupy full screen.

Comment: A simple fact "Neither regular images nor retina images wont fit in iPhone5". If we dont provide bigger size images, the images (either normal or retina) will be stretched in iPhone5 and wont look good. So, its a must to add 3 resolution images to the app.

Comment: Correct me: you mean to say that, we've to make the apps leaving space below the 2x images?

Comment: I'm not specific to any button or some control. It can be a background image as well, that has to stretch to full screen. In iPhone5, in order to fill the remaining space, developers may stretch their controls as well. And so definitely they need new images.

Comment: so just by adding 2x wont server the purpose. And so there's no naming convention at all for iPhone5. Even without 2x, it picks the images as coded by the developer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22311/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-satyam-svv)

Comment: so i have to make IBOutlet for all imageView to change its image name runtime?

Answer (score 2):

till now they have not released any official documentation for the iPhone5 Images.

You can do like this.

```
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()  == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale >= 1136)
{
//Write the code here for iPhone5 Image.
}
else
{
//this is for unto 4th gen iPhone
}
```

Comment: A hack, but it'll do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific naming convention for images on iPhone 5.
The Default-568h@2x will be shown on launch of an iPhone 5 or iPod Touch 5G. This will also enable the non-letterbox mode of your app. For your other f.e. background images you have to design flexible if you want to cover both screen resolutions. When you building an iPhone 4s App assure that f.e. a background image can be strechted up to the iPhone 5 size.

Answer (score 1):

> it is just the same. The @2x just means it's a retina image.
>
> The only difference is the 568@2x (or whatever it is) for the splash
>   screen but Xcode renames that file for you anyway.
>
> Just keep using @2x.png

I must add, that if you look at the simulator the pictures maybe stretched! You could fix this by checking the box (if u use storyboard) "auto layout" I have some problems too maybe this is a bug which will be fixed I hope...

[image: changing the size]

and on storyboard or .xib u can change the size of the controller like here:

[image]